# How can we achieve some*, anotherSome** in page and on bottom of page add it's detail [iTEXT]

Tags: itext

How to achieve case where in page, we have some content marked *, or ** and so on. And on the bottom of page describe what those are.

Like in page it's

[image: On page]

And on bottom

[image: On bottom of page]

I know this is not the footer as footer applies to all pages. It should be on some page only depending on content.

Please suggest.

Comment: You could use the `onEndPage()` event to add the notes to the current page and the current page alone, but that doesn't solve the most difficult problem: how are you going to adapt the bottom margin so that the notes fit the page? This can only be done if you use `ColumnText` and do the layout-related math yourself. That will require more programming than can be explained in an answer on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my `HeaderFooterPageEvent` I added a `private static int pageCounter = 0;` and `PdfPTable footerNoteTable;` and a method

```
public void setFooterTable(PdfPTable footerTable) {
    this.footerNoteTable = footerTable;
}
```

and on onStartPage() method or you can do it on onEndPage().

```
if (pageCounter == 0) {
    document.setMargins(36, 36, 150, 36);                                                       
    footerNoteTable.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 36, 90, writer.getDirectContent());
}
pageCounter++;
```

and on PDF generation class, I added

```
HeaderFooterPageEvent headerFooter = new HeaderFooterPageEvent();
headerFooter.setFooterTable(createFooterNote(document));
writer.setPageEvent(headerFooter);
document.setMargins(36, 36, 150, 95);
```

where `createFooterNote(document)` will return a PdfPTable required.

This way I achieved the desired result.

Idea is to set, different document margin for that particular page in the PageEvent and adding Table on the specified locaiton.

Hope this helps others :)